# Is it possible to add TOTP multi-factor authentication using the Firebase Admin Python SDK?

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, multi-factor-authentication

I'm having a bit of trouble navigating through some of the firebase documentation. I utilize the Firebase JS SDK on my web app and the Firebase Admin SDK (Python) within my back-end. I've enabled Identity Platform via GCP.

According to the docs here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/totp-mfa

```
If you haven't done so already, install the Firebase JavaScript SDK.

TOTP MFA is only supported on the modular Web SDK, versions v9.19.1 and above.

If you haven't done so already, install the Firebase Admin SDK.

TOTP MFA is only supported on Firebase Admin SDK versions 11.6.0 and above.
```

It's not specified that there's only Node.js support for this MFA feature, but I can't find any related documentation on how to do this in my Python/Flask environment. Is it possible to use this feature using the latest Firebase Admin Python SDK?

Thanks!

I've reviewed the documentation thus far and haven't been able to find any related resources/information on how I can get this to work. I do have Firebase Admin Python SDK in use within production.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the recent [releases of the Python Admin SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/releases) and don't see any mention of TOTP support there - so it seems that indeed this support was never added.

I recommend filing a feature request for it on the [`firebase-admin-python` repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python), or even better: submit a PR to add it.